# how to add a transition in d3 having already another one

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a sorting transition in my bar chart that has already another transition,but the sorting one should be applied when clicking a checkbox. If I remove the first transition that is just an animated visualization of the bars, the sorting one succeed, why? Hope you can help me.

Here's the code:

```
var graph= svg.selectAll(".bar")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("class","bar");

graph.append("svg:title")
           .text(function(d){
              return d["Regione"]+", "+d["2013"]; 
       });

var barchart= graph.attr("x",function(d){
               return xScale(d["Regione"]);
        })
           .attr("width",xScale.rangeBand())
           .attr("y",function(d){
               //return yScale(+d["2013"]);
               return height;
        })
           .transition().delay(function (d,i){ return i * 300;})
           .duration(300)
           .attr("height",function(d){
                return height-yScale(+d["2013"]);
        })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return  yScale(d["2013"]) ; });

       /************ sorting************/
 d3.select("input").on("change", change);

var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                   d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
                  }, 200);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

    var x0 = xScale.domain(data.sort(this.checked
        ? function(a, b) { return b["2013"] - a["2013"]; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a["Regione"], b["Regione"]); })
        .map(function(d) { return d["Regione"]; }))
        .copy();

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(1050),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d["Regione"]); });

    transition.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay)
        .selectAll("text")
        //.style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

 }
```

If I do not apply the first transition,the sorting works well, I can't figure out the problem. Thanks in advance!
[this is the csv file](http://www.filedropper.com/diffusionesitiweb)

thanks

Comment: Can you put this into a JSFiddle to help us help you?

Comment: Actually I'm not so practice with JSFiddle :( I have to import an external file :/,if i give you the file itself? thanks!

Comment: @canyon289  here it is the JSFiddle,but as i said i can't import my csv file  http://jsfiddle.net/p8qd03qv/

Comment: @canyon289 maybe I've solved,in a brutal but effective way;in practice the first transition during for about 7/8 seconds,and I let start the second one after 15s,so if i checked the checkbox,it will start earlier otherwise it starts automatically after 15s,and it this way there is no overlapping :) thanks for the support!